# RecyclerView items can't handle drag events after notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop

I have simple `RecyclerView` (nothing other on screen) with simple items (simple View with fixed height).

When long click on item triggered native drag event on `RecyclerView` called.

Each item has dragListener that called and in example I able to change view background during drag shadow entered or exited item.

But I have more complex case. During drag I need to update my items (in this example I triggered it by calling method `notifyDataSetChanged()` during `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION)`.

So problem is that after items changed during drag - they are not able to handle any drag events.

The code of my Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;

private View.OnLongClickListener onLongClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        recyclerView.startDrag(
                new ClipData(new ClipDescription("drag", new String[]{ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN}), new ClipData.Item("drag")),
                new View.DragShadowBuilder(v),
                null,
                0
        );
        return true;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(onLongClickListener));
}
}
```

And code of my adapter, where handling of drag events is present:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyListAdapter.Holder>{

private View.OnLongClickListener onLongClickListener;

public MyListAdapter(View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener) {
    onLongClickListener = longClickListener;
}

@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    final Holder holder = new Holder(view);

    view.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    holder.setSelected(true);
                    return true;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    holder.setSelected(false);
                    return true;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }
    });

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
    holder.setContent(position % 2 == 0 ? R.color.colorPrimary : R.color.colorAccent);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 100;
}

class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private View view;
    private int colorRes;

    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(onLongClickListener);
    }

    public void setContent(int colorRes) {
        this.colorRes = colorRes;
        view.setBackgroundResource(colorRes);
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(selected ? R.color.green : colorRes);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to use the 'notifyItemMoved' api: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html ... The notifyDataSetChange refreshes the entire list instead of just the relevant item/s.

Comment: @HedShafran No. As I said I have more complex case. And I'm not enough with methods like 'notifyItemMoved'. I really need refresh all content.

Comment: I know this is very late, but you're going to have to call "notifyItemChanged" for each index. This method doesn't interrupt dragging, and will re-bind the views that you change.